# Drools validate a primitive type

Tags: java, drools, primitive

What is the correct way to validate and use a primitive type in drools?
I want to validate id and insert the Long value to kieSession.

```
        when
        Long( Objects.isNull(this  ))
        then
        .....
```

but it does'nt work. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword is your friend, but you just do a straight-up `== null` or `!= null` check, no funny business with the `Objects.*` helpers.

```
Long( this != null )
Integer( this > 64 )
```

Alternatively if you really want to use `Objects.IsNull` or similar, you could assign the value and then pass to the method:

```
$value: Long()
Boolean(this == true) from Objects.isNull($value)
```

... though this is pretty convoluted. (You could also use eval instead of the Boolean...from; don't do that: eval is bad.)

`this` is always self-referential, even if Object is null. Note that you're using the primitive wrappers and not primitives, which protects you from the NPE caused by an implicit cast.

---

Alternatively if you're just checking that something is *not present* in working memory, you can use the `not(...)` operation:

```
not( SomeObject() )
not( String( this == "foo" ) )
not( Long( this == 42 ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer, I wonder why they don't work for me. I mean, although the value is null, the "then" clause does not fire.

Comment: Can't really say without knowing what your actual rule is, what the inputs are, and how you're firing them.